# How to avoid module conflicts in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I have model in rails app named Benchmark, although ruby requires its Benchmark module by default when starting process.

Is there anyway I can unload Benchmark module in order to use my Benchmark model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use a namespaced model.

```
module Myapp
  class Benchmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

You may need to specify the table name.

If I were you, I would just a different name for the model, e.g. Yardstick or Indicator or MyBenchmark.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally possible to unbind Ruby constants from their original names using logic like this:

```
require "benchmark"

BM = Benchmark
Object.send(:remove_const, :Benchmark)

class Benchmark
  def initialize
    puts "Hey, I'm your custom Benchmark"
  end

  ...
end
```

However, specifically for the original `Benchmark` implementation this won't work, as it's internally full of name references like this one:

```
@list << res = Benchmark.measure(label, &blk)
```

The best practical solution is to pick a "free" synonym to name your model.